# Django profile page for every user

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to show a page for every user in my app. I have these lines in views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import *  
def profiler(request, username):
        k = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        return render_to_response("profil.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^people/(?P<username>\d+)/$', profiler, name = "profiler"),
```

but it says page not found when I go to /people/m which should be a page for my user 'm'. How can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d+` matches digits only. You want `\w+` to match alphanumeric characters, or perhaps even `[\w_-]` to match underscores and dashes as well.